# Using class="sponsor_logo" or class="sponsor-logo" does not display the div

Tags: html, css

I noticed a strange behavior and cannot understand why this is happening, since they do seem to be valid CSS class names (they pass when tested against the regex).
using any other words in that pattern works, like happy-world or happy_world.
I have created a Codepen here to show what I am experiencing. check here https://codepen.io/akhatri7/pen/LYxMgOz

```css
div {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sponsorlogo {
  background-color: violet;
}

.sponsor-logo {
  background-color: indigo;
}

.sponsor_logo {
  background-color: blue;
}

.sponsor__logo {
  background-color: green;
}

.happy-world {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.happy_world {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sponsorlogo"></div>
<div class="sponsor-logo"></div>
<div class="sponsor_logo"></div>
<div class="sponsor__logo"></div>
<div class="happy-world"></div>
<div class="happy_world"></div>
```

Using class names `sponsor-logo` and `sponsor__logo` works fine.
Can someone please explain why this could be happening?

Comment: All of these are working fine on my end. I see the indigo box for sponsor-logo. Have you tried in another browser?

Comment: and i realised it is not an issue in all browsers, it displays correctly in IE edge but not in firefox and chrome. But displays correctly in chrome mobile

Comment: Works fine in Chrome for me. Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Comment: i am also on the same version, could it be due to OS? I have checked on windows (chrome and IE edge) and ubuntu (chromium and firefox), only worked in IE edge out of these

Comment: I doubt it.. dashes in class names is the most popular format and is not an issue at all so its strange you are experiencing this. Have you tried a completely different class name like sp-logo. I mean the only reason could be other css overriding it but in a codepen there is no other code..

Comment: checked on friend's M1 macbook, displays correctly on safari but not on chrome Version 90.0.4430.85 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: i tried sponsor-world, it works its the exact 2 words in these combinations that don't work, i am going crazy trying to know why this is happening. I myself have been using - and _ in class names since a long time

Comment: Yeah that is very strange indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The divs with classes `sponsor-logo` and `sponsor_logo` were not being displayed for me as well. But upon further inspection, I found that the `display` property of these two divs was set to **none** by an injected stylesheet.

Injected stylesheets are the ones that Chrome extensions can inject into pages. And the culprit was Adblock Plus, disable the extension and you will see the results are as expected.

Comment: I did not make any code modifications to the original code pen: https://codepen.io/akhatri7/pen/LYxMgOz. If you have Adblock Plus extension installed, disable it.